# how do I pass an u_id value to another activity?

Tags: java, android

Here is my main file where i get u_id and other data but i pass u_id text to other activity
Mainactivity.java

```
    package com.desktop.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_TITLE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
   Button signup,login,learnmore ;
   EditText ed1,ed2,u_id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbutton);
learnmore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.learnmore);
login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailedittext);
        u_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uid);
ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordedittext);




signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
});

learnmore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity1.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });


login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String email = ed1.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = ed2.getText().toString().trim();
         final String log_id = u_id.getText().toString();
        if(email.isEmpty()){
            ed1.setError("Fill this field");
            ed1.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(password.isEmpty()){
            ed2.setError("Fill this field");
            ed2.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if(log_id.isEmpty()){
            u_id.setError("Fill this field");
            u_id.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                login();
                Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this,fullview.class);
                Bundle b =new Bundle();
                b.putString("text", String.valueOf(u_id));
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        }
    private void login(){


        String url= "http://192.168.0.136/fyp/andr_log.php";
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.trim().equals("Login Successfull")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Search.class);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Unsuccessfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error:" +error.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Email", ed1.getText().toString().trim() );
                params.put("uid", u_id.getText().toString().trim() );
                params.put("Password", ed2.getText().toString().trim() );
                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }});
}
    }
```

fullview.java

```
    package com.desktop.app;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.*;

import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_AUTHOR;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_HR;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_PUBLISHER;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_PUBY;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_ACC;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_RAK;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_STATUS;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_TITLE;
import static com.desktop.app.Stitle.EXTRA_VR;

public class fullview extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button location, avail, request;
    TextView textviewtitle, textviewauthors, textviewpublisher, textviewpubyear,textviewacc,u_id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullview);


        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String id= b.getString("text");
        u_id= findViewById(R.id.uid);

        String title = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE);
        String author = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_AUTHOR);
        String publisher = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PUBLISHER);

        int  puby = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_PUBY,0);
        int  accc = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ACC,0);
         final int  rak = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_RAK,0);
         final int  hr = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_HR,0);
         final int  vr = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_VR,0);
        final String status = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_STATUS);

        textviewtitle = findViewById(R.id.textviewtitle);
        textviewauthors = findViewById(R.id.textviewauthors);
        textviewpublisher = findViewById(R.id.textviewpublisher);
        textviewpubyear = findViewById(R.id.textviewpubyear);
        textviewacc = findViewById(R.id.textviewacc);

        textviewtitle.setText(title);
        textviewauthors.setText(author);
        textviewpublisher.setText(publisher);
        textviewpubyear.setText(String.valueOf(puby));
        textviewacc.setText(String.valueOf(accc));

        location = findViewById(R.id.loc);
        location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(fullview.this);

                    builder.setTitle("Location");
                    builder.setMessage("Rak-No :: " + rak +  "\nColumn :: " + hr +"\nRow :: " + vr);
                    AlertDialog alertDialog=null;

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(fullview.this,"Closed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog=builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            }
        });

        avail = findViewById(R.id.avail);
        avail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(fullview.this);
                    {
                        if (status.equals("yes")) {
                            builder.setTitle("Availablity");
                            builder.setMessage("Available");
                        } else {
                        builder.setTitle("Availablity");
                        builder.setMessage("Not Available");
                    }
                    }
                    AlertDialog alertDialog=null;

                    builder.setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(fullview.this,"Closed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog=builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
        });
        request= findViewById(R.id.request);
        request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                request();
            }
        });

    }
    private void request(){


        String url= "http://192.168.0.136/fyp/bookreq.php";
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(fullview.this);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.trim().equals("successfull")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go to Admin For Approval",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent(fullview.this,Search.class);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Requested",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error:" +error.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                params.put("Title", textviewtitle.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("Author", textviewauthors.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("Publisher", textviewpublisher.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("Acc", textviewacc.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("Puby", textviewpubyear.getText().toString().trim());
                Log.i("Info",textviewtitle.getText().toString().trim());

                return params;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    }
```

Here is my second file above where i want to shoe u_id text but i done with this to pass u_id text to other activity

```
Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this,fullview.class);
Bundle b =new Bundle();
b.putString("text", String.valueOf(u_id));
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

this code i use to pass u_id text and next activity code i use below code

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        String id= b.getString("text");

        u_id= findViewById(R.id.uid);
```

Comment: instaed of String.valueOf(u_id).... can you try u_id.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: So what went wrong?

Comment: i pass value but it not display @Psypher

Comment: logcat got value this >> "I/uid: Bundle[{text=10-arid-1010}]"  @Psypher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your problem is.

```
Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this,fullview.class);
Bundle b =new Bundle();
b.putString("text", String.valueOf(u_id));
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

Change this line

```
b.putString("text", String.valueOf(u_id));
```

to

```
b.putString("text", u_id.getText().toString().trim());
```

EDIT:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String email = ed1.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = ed2.getText().toString().trim();
         final String log_id = u_id.getText().toString();
        if(email.isEmpty()){
            ed1.setError("Fill this field");
            ed1.requestFocus();
        }else if(password.isEmpty()){
            ed2.setError("Fill this field");
            ed2.requestFocus();
        } else if(log_id.isEmpty()){
            u_id.setError("Fill this field");
            u_id.requestFocus();
        } else {
                login();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,fullview.class);
                Bundle b =new Bundle();
                b.putString("text", u_id.getText().toString().trim());
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
           }


        }
```

Comment: logcat got value this >> "I/uid: Bundle[{text=10-arid-1010}]" @DroiDev

Comment: whatever the value is in the edit test is what will be passed. you can also create a simle button to test it to make sure its work. when u click the button, doa toast of the text within the edit text. but thats the proper way of getting the text from an edit text.

Comment: logcat got value this >> "I/uid: Bundle[{text=10-arid-1010}]" @DroiDev

Comment: its also not working because you have a nested onclick listener

Comment: dont just copy and paste it. i dont think the syntax is right.... but thatll give you an idea. check the edit above @AsadMallick

Comment: do if /else statements... not if statements.

Comment: and btw, your code is all over the place. you have login() method.... which goes into a different activity than where you are sending them inwith that intent. you need to really look at your logic, because it looks completely wrong

Comment: i want to pass value from Mainactivity.java to fullview.java @DroiDev

Comment: right.... but you have login() method at the top of that intent code... it will run the login method before getting to that intent method. you might need more logic there.... but what i have for you should do what you asked for.

Comment: now i run intent method before login() then same case appear as before.. i just want to pass value and show in fullview activity .. kindly resolse my issue @DroiDev

Comment: in your fullview,  you never set the text. u_id.setText(id);

Comment: i use text. u_id.setText(id);  and logcat >> "I/uid: null" @DroiDev

Comment: ok, so its passing null. comment everything out inside of the login.setonclicklistener. and do a log to see if you can even grab the text properly in the edit text. from there, build it out. you are missing a simple solution here and your code is all over the place its hard to follow.

Comment: **I/uid: Bundle[{text=14-arid-3674}]
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/asd: 14-arid-3674
I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9317e7a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa269f7c0)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9317e7a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa269f7c0)**

Comment: logcat given above @DroiDev
**I/uid: Bundle[{text=14-arid-3674}] ** this is from Mainactivity
**I/asd: 14-arid-3674** this if from fullview activity ... i think so

Comment: dont use a bundle here.... just craete an onclick listener.... and when u click the button, log the text from the edit text...just to make sure that works.

Comment: maybe someone else cna chime in from here.... not sure if you are understanding waht im telling you to do